# Python SciPy is 'RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt' bad?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I wanted to fit some astronomical data (made up data mostly), using a gaussian function on a line. I took the residual of the gaussian+line function on x-axis so I only had to fit the gaussian. Here's how I defined it:

```
def gaussian_only(x, amp,  mean, std):
    curve = amp*np.exp(-(x-mean)**2 /( 2*std**2 ) ) * np.sqrt(std)/np.sqrt(std) * np.sqrt(amp)/np.sqrt(amp) * np.sqrt(mean)/np.sqrt(mean)
    return curve
```

I multiplied and divided by sqrt of the values as the curvefit (defined in another function) was returning me negative values for standard deviation, mean and amplitude. So this kind of forced it to return me only positive values.
Here's the function:

```
def gaussian_only_fit(arr, curve_residual, initial_guess):
    amp, mean, std = initial_guess
    fit = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(gaussian_only, arr[0], curve_residual, [amp,mean,std])
    return fit
```

Is there something "wrong" or "bad" with what I did?
EDIT:
I did try "bounds" argument for curve_fit. It gives me worse fit values than before.

Answer (score 1):

curve_fit() probably attempted to evaluate your function with a negative value of `std`.

You can use the `bounds` argument of curve_fit() to avoid this. You should probably also avoid fitting with 0 standard deviation, so set a very small positive value as the lower bound:

```
fit = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(gaussian_only, arr[0], curve_residual, [amp,mean,std], bounds=([0, -inf, 1e-15],[inf, inf, inf]))
```

Given your application, I've also set the minimum value for `amp` to 0 here. Depending on what the data represents you might also want to set limits on `mean`.

Note the `bounds` argument was only introduced in scipy version 0.17. If you are using an older version of scipy, you could use a variable transformation like

```
def gaussian_only(x, log_amp,  log_mean, log_std):
    amp = np.exp(log_amp)         # Guarantees 0 < amp < infinity
    mean = np.exp(log_mean)
    std = np.exp(log_std)
    curve = amp*np.exp(-(x-mean)**2 /( 2*std**2 ) )
    return curve
```

Of course you will have to adjust your starting guess to account for the transformation.

Comment: I did try bounds but that gave me bad fit values for my data. In fact, with bounds, the values were so much worse than the negative values which I were getting.